# Spy with mockito a class extending ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, mockito, spy

Hello anyone would know how to spy a class that is extending `ArrayBlockingQueue`? For example I want to spy the following `MyBufferQueue` class

```java
public class MyBufferQueue extends ArrayBlockingQueue<MyBuffer> {}
```

Inside of `ArrayBlockingQueue` class that belongs to java library, there is this method:

```java
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
   Objects.requireNonNull(e);
   final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
   lock.lockInterruptibly();
   try {
       while (count == items.length)
       notFull.await();
       enqueue(e);
   } finally {
       lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I am spying the class `MyBufferQueue` and during the test when it is accessed the method `ArrayBlockingQueue.put(E e)`, I am getting a `NullPointerException` in `this.lock`, when it is supposed that it shouldn't be `null` as I am creating a new instance of `MyBufferQueue` in my test, and when creating the new instance the fields inside of `ArrayBlockingQueue` should be instantiated too as `ArrayBlockingQueue` is the super class.

This is how would look the test method:

```java
@Test
void testMyBuffer() {
    MyBufferQueue queue = spy(new MyBufferQueue(1));
    doNothing().when(queue).retryAll();
    
    queue.consumeFullQueue();

    verify(queue).retryAll();
}
```

For spying I am using Mockito version mockito-core:4.7.0 and I am using Java 18.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem recently, and it's caused by how Java 17 and up (possibly earlier, but at least after Java 11) works in combination with Mockito. Instance fields of spied objects remain `null`.

The solution is very simple - replace `mockito-core` with `mockito-inline`. Same groupId, same version, just a different artifactId.

Comment: Thanks! Just by adding `mockito-inline` looks to work for me now, now when spying `MyBufferQueue`, the fields of the super class are not giving me now `NullPointerException`, and now the test is passing. What I couldn't do is to replace `mockito-core` with `mockito-inline`, maven was including me `mockito-core` even after adding `<exclusion>` in pom for that dependency. So I have included both of them in the pom file.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, following this [page](https://www.davidvlijmincx.com/posts/writing_higher_quality_tests_with_mockitos_inline_mock_maker/), they explain that it can be added Mockito's inline by adding `mockito-core` and `mockito-inline` dependencies in your pom, it looks like it is not needed to replace it with `mockito-core`, both of them have to be as dependencies in your pom.

Comment: @user3419082 you shouldn't exclude `mockito-core`, it's still needed. As you found out, if you include `mockito-inline` you transitively include `mockito-core`, and that's just fine. I just prefer to not duplicate version numbers. Sorry for the confusion.